# Template literals in ngStyle directive

Tags: angular

Why someone can't use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in angular2 [`ngStyle`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) directive? For example, this code:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background': `linear-gradient(black ${percent}%, white ${percent}%`}">test text</div>
```

(where `percent` is a variable inside component) gives error

> Unexpected token Lexer Error: Unexpected character [`]

Comment: I guess you can still get them with a method, like <div [ngStyle]="{'background': getTheClassName()}">test text</div> and then in getClassName(){ return "linear-gradient(black ${percent}%, white ${percent}%")}. Didn't test though

Comment: Yes, you are right, and even i can replace template literals with string concatenation (`'linear-gradient(black ' + percent + '}%, white ' + percent + '%'`). Just curious why template literals don't work in that place.

Comment: Where did you find that it is supported by angular?

Comment: i didn't find information about support template literals somewhere, but it seemed strange for me that i can use string concatenation but not template literals